# Using char* in C++ for conversion from binary to decimal and decimal to binary

Tags: c++, binary, char, decimal

UPDATE:

```
char* DecToBin(int n){
    char* ptr = new char[];
    char* CharReturn = new char[9];
    CharReturn[0] = n % 2;
    CharReturn[1] = n % 3;
    ptr = CharReturn;
    return ptr;
}
```

Got everything else figured out, but i can not get this char* to return any practical values. How do I allocate memory for the char*(pointer). How can I implement a bit function like (x & 1), (x >> 1), and how would you use (x == 0), would be something like the parameter in a for loop?

ORIGINAL QUESTION

---

thank you for reading my question. I have a problem for my programming class that requires the use of `char*` to convert from binary to decimal and decimal to binary using a switch statement, The code I have so far is very rough and not at all finished. I am having a problem understanding the use of the `char*`, The program must use the functions

```
int BinToDec(char* s);

char* DecToBin(int n);
```

I am a beginner level programmer, this is my third semester and I have never programmed in C++. This assignment is for my CPS 260, programming in Assembly class. Im trying to do the best I can, I mainly want to know if I'm working in the right direction. I know the algorithms to find binary and decimal are rough.

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int BinToDec(char* s);
char* DecToBin(int n);

int BinToDec(char* BinIn){

    int intOut = 0;
        intOut = intOut + BinIn[0] * 128;
        intOut = intOut + BinIn[1] * 64;
        intOut = intOut + BinIn[2] * 32;
        intOut = intOut + BinIn[3] * 16;
        intOut = intOut + BinIn[4] * 8;
        intOut = intOut + BinIn[5] * 4;
        intOut = intOut + BinIn[6] * 2;
        intOut = intOut + BinIn[7] * 1;
        return intOut;
}

char* DecToBin(){

    unsigned int intInput, Holder;
    char charReturn[7];
    char* ptr;

    cout << "Please Enter the num number you wish to convert to Binary. \n";
    cin >> intInput;
    Holder = intInput % 2;
    charReturn[0] = Holder;
    Holder = intInput / 2;
    charReturn[1] = Holder % 2;


    ptr = charReturn;
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    bool done = false;
    unsigned short int intSelect;

    while (!done)
    {
        cout << "Please select a conversion type: \n";
        cout << "1. Convert from Binary to Decimal \n";
        cout << "2. Convert from Decimal to Binary \n";
        cout << "3. Exit the program. \n";
        cin >> (intSelect);

        switch (intSelect)
        {
        case 1: //How to call BinToDec()
        {
        char* Input;
        cout << "Please enter the 8-bit binary:\n";
        cin >> (Input);
        BinToDec(Input);
        break; }

        case 2: //How to call DecToBin()
        {cout << "case 2\n";
        cout << DecToBin();
        system("pause");
        break; }

        case 3: //Exit
        {cout << "The Program will now exit\n";
        system("pause");
        done = true;
        break; }

        default: //Check others
        {cout << "Invalid Entry try again. \n\n";
        return 0;
        }
        }

    }
    cout << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Any input will be very constructive, even if it's saying I'm a horrible programmer and headed in the entirely wrong direction.
Thank you ahead of time, even if you don't post a reply.

P.S. I have programmed in Java and Visual Basic, with no experience in C++ And am still working on the use of functions. Do you have to declare them first?

Comment: Another course on c++ that forces you to use char* instead of strings? Oh god.

Comment: More on topic, I'll try to write out some helpful notes: 1) C++ requires you to initialize your variables -> charReturn[7] is an array of 7 chars, with undefined values as you are using it currently. You need to have it end with 0 (`\0`), because C style strings (char*) are just an array of many characters, with 0 noting end of the string. Also it is locally allocated, so if you return pointer to the array, you will get garbage values. (You need to have it heap allocated, look up `malloc`, `new`.) You also need to allocate more space. ;-)

Comment: Are strings and char* similar in there function, the class is for Assembly, were doing our High Level programming in C++. If that makes more sense for the use of char*. Thank you for the reply.    EDIT: I had it stored as an array of [7] because I was thinking 0-7, we only need to convert 8-bit binary numbers. Would an array of [8] be more appropriate, and i will look into malloc, new, All i have been getting out for cout << has been garbage characters. Where would the \0 go in the brackets?

Comment: 2) The usual convention is to state as clearly as possible, what you want to happen. You don't exactly do that: instead of using `% 2` and `/ 2`, use bit operations. (Because that is essentially what you are doing: take lowest bit (`x & 1`), shift the number down (`x >> 1`), repeat until the whole number is consumed (`x == 0`). (Btw, you should do dec->bin conversion with a loop.) 3) `std::cin >> <char*>` doesn't work without given `char*` pointing to valid, `malloc`-ed or `new`-ed memory. This should help you get started. (And please note that this was not exhaustive list, just first glance)

Comment: Im trying to get the basic principle working without the complication of a loop, I will use a loop once I get it figured out, thank you again for your quick reply and help!

Comment: I will elaborate on the C-style strings bit more: C-style strings (aka `char*`) are null terminated, that is, if you have `char string[] = "Hello";`, the actual size of the string array is 6, and the initialization is equivalent with `char strings[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};`. (Note that `'\0'` is literal for character with integer value of 0, while '0' is something different.) Pretty much every function that talks about strings in C, in reality talks about a piece of memory (array of `char`s), that it then reads until it finds first null (or crashes program :-) ), and works with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that the length of your binary integer is no more than 8 bits.

To call BinToDec()

```
char Input[9];
cout << "Please enter the 8-bit binary:\n";
cin >> (Input);
cout << BinToDec(Input);
```

you need to create a char array which has least 8+1 elements, the last element of a char array string is always 0.

```
int BinToDec(char* BinIn){

    int intOut = 0;
    intOut = intOut + (BinIn[0]-'0') * 128;
    //convert '0' or '1' to 0 or 1.
    intOut = intOut + (BinIn[1]-'0') * 64;
    intOut = intOut + (BinIn[2]-'0') * 32;
    intOut = intOut + (BinIn[3]-'0') * 16;
    intOut = intOut + (BinIn[4]-'0') * 8;
    intOut = intOut + (BinIn[5]-'0') * 4;
    intOut = intOut + (BinIn[6]-'0') * 2;
    intOut = intOut + (BinIn[7]-'0') * 1;
    return intOut;
}
```

Inside DecToBin()

```
unsigned int intInput, Holder;
//char charReturn[7];
//if you make it 7, you can only convert from 0-63
char* ptr;
char* charReturn = new char[9];

cout << "Please Enter the num number you wish to convert to Binary. \n";
cin >> intInput;
Holder = intInput % 2;
charReturn[0] = Holder+'0';
//Holder is 0 or 1, you need to convert it to '0' or '1'
Holder = intInput / 2;
charReturn[1] = Holder % 2+'0';
//...
charReturn[8] = 0; //last character is 0 in char* style string.
ptr = charReturn;
return ptr;
```

You need to use `new` or `malloc` to create an array so that it is stored in the memory after the function returned.